# How many different permutations of the letters  contain the strings  and ?

Tags: probability

How many different permutations of the letters  contain
the strings  and ?

**My attempt**

I thought it to be $\frac{5!}{2}$ since there are 2 b's which are being repeated but I am not sure whether this correct or not. Can anyone please help with this.

Comment: Do the strings have to be consecutive?

Comment: That is the only way, I think. We are asking for permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CABED must be together. So there are four "letters": F,G,H and "CABED".

Thus, there are 24 ways to arrange this.

Comment: So, I need to combine CABED and consider it as '1'

Comment: Yes, because B is after C and A, also before E and D. Thus, these five letters must be arranged in that order.